# Can somebody explain the steps in this recurrence back substitution problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm usually good until the first couple of steps, then once you add more and more things I get lost pretty easily. Can somebody give me a step-by-step analysis of this? I'd really appreciate it.

$$T_{n} = 4T_{n-1} - 2, T_{0} = 1$$

$$T_{n} = 4[4T_{n-2} - 2] - 2$$

$$T_{n} = 4^2 T_{n-2} - 4 * 2 - 2$$

$$T_{n} = 4^2 T_{n-2} - 2(1+4)$$

$$T_{n} = 4^2[4T_{n-3} - 2] - 2(1+4)$$

$$T_{n} = 4^3 T_{n-3} - 2 * 4^2 - 2(1+4)$$

$$T_{n} = 4^3 T_{n-3} - 2(1 + 4 + 4^2$$

$$T_{n} = 4^3 [T_{n-4} - 2] - 2(1 + 4 + 4^2)$$

$$T_{n} = 4^4 T_{n-4} - 4^3 * 2 * 2(1+4+4^2)$$

$$T_{n} = 4^4 T_{n-4} - 2(1+4+4^2 + 4^3) \\ \vdots \\ T_{n} = 4^k T_{n-k} - 2(1+4+4^2 +...+ 4^{k+1})$$

Comment: Do you know how to use mathematical induction?

Comment: I take it the first line is the recurrence relation and the other stuff is work but, what exactly are you trying to do here? (ie for those of us who aren't in your class what does a "recurrence back substitution problem" ask of you).

Comment: I do not know how to use induction. My professor said that this wasn't induction.

Comment: So what *exactly* are you asking?

Comment: I'm trying to find a pattern from the relation given to me. Apologies if it wasn't clear, I thought back substitution was a common thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea
is that you do successive substitutions
until you see a pattern.
Then,
you prove the pattern by induction.

Your case:

$T_{n} 
= 4T_{n-1} - 2, 
T_{0} = 1
$.

First step is to
substitute for
$T_{n-1}$
using the recurrence.
Since
$T_{n-1} 
= 4T_{n-2} - 2
$,
we
get
$T_{n} 
= 4T_{n-1} - 2
= 4(4T_{n-2} - 2) - 2
= 16T_{n-2} - 8 - 2
$.

Do the same for
$T_{n-2}$.
we get
$T_{n} 
= 16T_{n-2} - 8 - 2
= 16(4T_{n-3} - 2) - 8 - 2
= 64T_{n-3} - 32 - 8 - 2
$.

Now we begin to see a pattern.
Writing the constants
as power of $2$,
we have
$T_{n} 
= 2^6T_{n-3} - 2^5 - 2^3 - 2^1
$.
With a little bit of manipulation,
this becomes
$T_{n} 
= 2^6T_{n-3} - 2(2^4 + 2^2 + 2^0)
$.
Since all the exponents are even,
we can write this using powers of $4$
(instead of powers of $2$)
as
$T_{n} 
= 4^3T_{n-3} - 2(4^2 + 4^1 +4^0)
$.

Looking at this,
the pattern seems to be,
for integer $k$,
$T_{n} 
= 4^kT_{n-k} - 2(4^{k-1} + 4^{k-2}+...+4^1 +4^0)
$.

Using the recurrence,
and writing
$T_{n-k}$
in terms of
$T_{n-k-1}$,
this is easy to prove.

If we set $n=k$,
this becomes

$\begin{array}\\
T_{n} 
&= 4^nT_{0} - 2(4^{n-1} + 4^{n-2}+...+4^1 +4^0)\\
&= 4^n - 2\frac{4^n-1}{4-1}\\
&= \frac{3\cdot4^n-2(4^n-1)}{3}\\
&= \frac{4^n+2}{3}\\
\end{array}
$.

You can easily verify this.
$T(0)
=\frac{1+2}{3}
=1
$.

$\begin{array}\\
4T_{n-1}-2
&=4\frac{4^{n-1}+2}{3}-2\\
&=\frac{4(4^{n-1}+2)-3\cdot2}{3}\\
&=\frac{4^{n}+8-6}{3}\\
&=\frac{4^{n}+2}{3}\\
&=T_{n}\\
\end{array}
$.

And we are done.